# tornado asynch reverse DNS lookup

Tags: python, tornado, reverse-dns

I want to add to my web app a reverse DNS lookup to check the authenticity of googlebot user agents, as google suggests in their [webmasters tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en). Is there any standard way of doing this asynchronously? I have not been able to find anything in the tornado docs. All I found was [this](https://github.com/eklitzke/tornado-dns) Github project that lists reverse DNS as a future feature. Is there any way to avoid blocking for reverse DNS lookups?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either call `socket.gethostbyaddr` in a `ThreadPoolExecutor` or use `pycares` (doing something like what's in `tornado.platform.caresresolver' but for`gethostbyaddr`instead of`getaddrinfo`)